# Mixed Effects Model with Nesting

Tags: r, mixed-model, model, nested-data, lme4-nlme

I have data collected from an experiment organized as follows:

Two sites, each with 30 trees. 15 are treated, 15 are control at each site. From each tree, we sample three pieces of the stem, and three pieces of the roots, so 6 level 1 samples per tree which is represented by one of two factor levels (root, stem). Then, from those stem / root samples, we take two samples by dissecting different tissues within the sample, which is represented by one of two factor levels for tissue type (tissue type A, tissue type B). These samples are measured as a continuous variable. Total number of observations is 720; 2 sites * 30 trees * (three stem samples + three root samples) * (one tissue A sample + one tissue B sample). Data looks like this...

```
        ï..Site Tree Treatment Organ Sample Tissue Total_Length
    1        L  LT1         T     R      1 Phloem           30
    2        L  LT1         T     R      1  Xylem           28
    3        L  LT1         T     R      2 Phloem           46
    4        L  LT1         T     R      2  Xylem           38
    5        L  LT1         T     R      3 Phloem          103
    6        L  LT1         T     R      3  Xylem           53
    7        L  LT1         T     S      1 Phloem           29
    8        L  LT1         T     S      1  Xylem           21
    9        L  LT1         T     S      2 Phloem           56
    10       L  LT1         T     S      2  Xylem           49
    11       L  LT1         T     S      3 Phloem           41
    12       L  LT1         T     S      3  Xylem           30
```

I am attempting to fit a mixed effects model using R and lme4, but am new to mixed models. I'd like to model the response as the Treatment + Level 1 Factor (stem, root) + Level 2 Factor (tissue A, tissue B), with random effects for the specific samples nested within the two levels.

In R, I am doing this using lmer, as follows

```
fit <- lmer(Response ~ Treatment + Organ + Tissue + (1|Tree/Organ/Sample))
```

From my understanding (...which is not certain, and why I am posting!) the term:

```
(1|Tree/Organ/Sample)
```

Specifies that 'Sample' is nested within the organ samples, which is nested within the tree. Is this sort of nesting relevant / valid? Sorry if this question is not clear, if so, please specify where I can elaborate.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think this is correct.

- `(1|Tree/Organ/Sample)` expands to/is equivalent to `(1|Tree)+(1|Tree:Organ)+(1|Tree:Organ:Sample)` (where `:` denotes an interaction).
- The fixed factors `Treatment`, `Organ` and `Tissue` automatically get handled at the correct level.
- You should probably include `Site` as a fixed effect (conceptually it's a random effect, but it's not practical to try to estimate among-site variance with only two sites); this will reduce the among-tree variance slightly.
- You should probably include all the data within a data frame, and pass this explicitly to `lmer` via a `data=my.data.frame` argument.

You may find the [glmm FAQ](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) helpful (it's focused on GLMMs but does have stuff relevant to linear mixed models as well).

Comment: What if Erik wanted to specify a covariance structure for these intercepts? I.e. one might expect a sample with a positive Tree intercept to also have a positive Organ intercept. Does the nesting take care of this issue automatically? If not, how could one specify such a structure?

Comment: I think if you try to write out the equations for that case you'll find that it's taken care of.

Comment: @BenBolker In this situation, we have `organ` as a fixed effect, but also as part of the random structure in `(1|Tree:Organ)+(1|Tree:Organ:Sample)`. Was this what you intended ? If so I would be interested in your reasoning.

Comment: Yes, that is intended. If you don't include `Organ` as a fixed effect, then you will be assuming that the differences between levels (Root and Stem) are exactly zero on average, across all levels. That's an unusual model (only makes sense if there is some constraint in the design that enforces it, or as a null model for comparing against a full model to estimate a significance level for the main effect of organ).

Answer (score 18):

I read this question and Dr. Bolker's answer, and tried to replicate the data (not caring much, frankly, about what "length" represents in biological terms or units, and then fit the model as above. I'm posting the results here to share and seek feedback as to the probable presence of misunderstandings.

The code I used to generate this fictional data can be found [here](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/Trees%20mixed%20random%20effects), and the data set has the inner structure of the OP:

```
     site     tree treatment organ sample tissue    length
1    L       LT01         T  root      1  phloem  108.21230
2    L       LT01         T  root      1  xylem   138.54267
3    L       LT01         T  root      2  phloem   68.88804
4    L       LT01         T  root      2  xylem   107.91239
5    L       LT01         T  root      3  phloem   96.78523
6    L       LT01         T  root      3  xylem    88.93194
7    L       LT01         T  stem      1  phloem  101.84103
8    L       LT01         T  stem      1  xylem   118.30319
```

The structure is as follows:

```
 'data.frame':  360 obs. of  7 variables:
     $ site     : Factor w/ 2 levels "L","R": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ tree     : Factor w/ 30 levels "LT01","LT02",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ treatment: Factor w/ 2 levels "C","T": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ organ    : Factor w/ 2 levels "root","stem": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
     $ sample   : num  1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ tissue   : Factor w/ 2 levels "phloem","xylem": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
     $ length   : num  108.2 138.5 68.9 107.9 96.8 ...
```

The data set was "rigged" (feedback here would be welcome) as follows:

1. For `treatment`, there is a fixed effect with two distinct intercepts for treatment versus controls (`100` versus `70`), and no random effects.
2. I set the values for `tissue` with prominent fixed effects with very different intercepts for `phloem` versus `xylem` (`3` versus `6`), and random effects with a `sd = 3`.
3. For `organ` there are two random intercept "contributions" from a $N(0,3)$ (i.e. `sd = 3`) with a fixed effect contribution to the intercept of `6` for both `root` and `stem`.
4. For `tree` we just have random effects with a `sd = 7`.
5. For `sample` I tried to set up only random effects with `sd = 5`.
6. For for `site` also just random eff's with `sd = 3`.

There were no slopes set up, due to the categorical nature of the variables.

The results of the mixed effects model:

```
fit <- lmer(length ~ treatment + organ + tissue + (1|tree/organ/sample), data = trees)
```

were:

```
 Random effects:
 Groups              Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 sample:(organ:tree) (Intercept) 9.534e-14 3.088e-07
 organ:tree          (Intercept) 0.000e+00 0.000e+00
 tree                (Intercept) 4.939e+01 7.027e+00
 Residual                        3.603e+02 1.898e+01
Number of obs: 360, groups:  sample:(organ:tree), 180; organ:tree, 60; tree, 30

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  79.8623     2.7011  52.5000  29.567  < 2e-16 ***
treatmentT   21.4368     3.2539  28.0000   6.588 3.82e-07 ***
organstem     0.1856     2.0008 328.0000   0.093    0.926    
tissuexylem   3.1820     2.0008 328.0000   1.590    0.113    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

How did it work out:

1. For `treatment` the intercept without treatment was `79.8623` (I set up a mean of `70`), and with treatment it was `79.8623 + 21.4368 = 101.2991` (we set up a mean of `100`.
2. For `tissue` there was a `3.1820` contribution to the intercept courtesy of `xylem`, and I had set up a difference between `phloem` and `xylem` of `3`. The random effects were not part of the model.
3. For `organ`, samples from the `stem` increased the intercept by `0.1856` - I had set up no difference in fixed effects between `stem` and `root`. The standard deviation of what I wanted to act as random effects was not reflected.
4. The `tree` random effects with a sd of `7` surfaced nicely as `7.027`.
5. As for `sample`, the initial `sd` of `5` was underemphasized as `3.088`.
6. `site` was not part of the model.

So, overall, it seems as though the model matches the structure of the data.