# Nested mixed effects with lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, tukey-hsd-test

I am trying to analyze data from an experiment using lme4. In the experiment, subjects saw either dark or bright versions of 50 stimuli (between-subjects; fixed effect "brightness"). All subjects saw the 50 stimuli 3 times in varying durations (within-subjects). A previous post ([Mixed Effects Model with Nesting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79360/mixed-effects-model-with-nesting)) suggested that the following code is the correct way to deal with the nesting in the data:

```
lmer(response ~ brightness+duration +(1|subject:duration),REML=FALSE,data=dat)
```

Is (1|subject:duration) the correct way of specifying the nested data structure (that each subject saw each stimulus in multiple durations)?

Furthermore, a tutorial (http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial2.pdf) recommends the use of random slopes for random factors. Is this appropriate here?

Edit: The factor duration has 3 levels that I compare using Tukey tests

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would say

```
response ~ brightness+duration+(duration|subject)
```

would probably be a little better. (The simpler `(1|duration:subject)` model is not necessarily wrong, but might be oversimplified.  If I were a peer reviewer of this work I would certainly ask for a justification of the simpler model ...) The `(duration|subject)` model is a "random-slopes" model, more or less (although if you have coded `duration` as a categorical (factor or ordered factor) variable the thing that varies randomly among subjects is not a slope *per se*, but a between-duration difference).  The specification you have (`(1|subject:duration)`) assumes all subject-duration effects are drawn from a single (iid) Normal distribution; `(duration|subject)` assumes that the duration effects for a single individual are drawn from a $3 \times 3$ multivariate Normal distribution.

More precisely: comparing the random effect specification `(1|subject:duration)` gives the model for the conditional modes/BLUPs of subject $s$ for duration $d$ (or duration *effect* $d$, depending on how the model is parameterized)
$$
b_{sd} \sim \textrm{Normal}(0,\sigma_{sd}^2)
$$
whereas `(duration|subject)` gives

$$
\begin{split}
b_{s\cdot} & \sim \textrm{MVN}( \mathbf 0,\Sigma) \\
\Sigma & = \left( 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
\sigma^2_1 & \sigma_{12} & \sigma_{13} \\
\sigma_{12} & \sigma^2_{2} & \sigma_{23} \\
\sigma_{13} & \sigma_{23} & \sigma^2_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{split}
$$
i.e., the different duration levels each have different among-subjects variances, and the among-subject variation in different duration levels is correlated ($\Sigma$ is a general symmetric positive (semi)definite matrix). To get back to the previous model you would need to restrict $\sigma_1^2=\sigma_2^2=\sigma_3^2=\sigma_{sd}^2$ and all of the off-diagonal elements would be zero.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your formula exactly specifies, in particular why your suggestion assumes a 3 X 3 normal distribution.

Comment: In addition, is the formula I entered above clearly wrong or still acceptable given the experiment design?

Comment: In this answer, is the correct `lmer()` syntax for the simpler model `(1|subject:duration)` or is it `(1|duration:subject)`?  I see the second version used at the beginning of the answer, but the first version is used later on.

Comment: it doesn't matter. The interaction operator `:` is commutative, except in some cases for the specific labels that get assigned -- but in this case even the labels are never explicitly shown.

Comment: however, note that `(duration|subject)` and `(subject|duration)` are *not* equivalent -- only the first is at all sensible