# How to simulate a random slope model

Tags: r, mixed-model, simulation

I would like do create a mixed linear model for an unbalanced dataset (different number of events per subject and a few missing values for some time points).  I am using `R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)`, `package: nlme_3.1-120`.

Here comes simulated data:

```
library(nlme)
set.seed(1)
subject    <- factor(rep(c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 
                           11, 11, 11, 12, 13), 10))
event      <- factor(rep(1:20, 10))
timepoint  <- rep(1:10, each = 20)
measure    <- rnorm(length(timepoint)) + timepoint*0.3
timepoint  <- factor(timepoint)
measure[sample(1:length(measure), rpois(5,4))] <- NA
data       <- data.frame(subject=subject, event=event, timepoint=timepoint, 
                         measure=measure)
str(data)
```

The model should predict the variable “measure” over different time points as fixed effect and for subjects and events as random effects.

```
base      <- lme(measure ~ 1,         data=data, random= ~ 1|subject, 
                 na.action=na.exclude, method="ML")
intercept <- lme(measure ~ timepoint, data=data, random= ~ 1|subject, 
                 na.action=na.exclude, method="ML")
nested    <- lme(measure ~ timepoint, data=data, random= ~ 1|subject/event, 
                 na.action=na.exclude, method="ML")
anova(base, intercept, nested)
```

I would like to fit random intercept and slope, because intercept and slope can vary among subjects and events. However when I add the random slope effect, the model does not converge. It does not through any error message, but it runs to infinity. What can I do create a model with random slope that converges?

**cave** model runs endless

```
slope <- lme(measure ~ timepoint, data=data, random= ~ timepoint|subject, 
             na.action=na.exclude, method="ML")
```

I tried also this

**cave** model runs endless

```
slope2 <- lme(measure ~ timepoint, data=data, random= ~ timepoint|subject, 
              na.action=na.exclude, method="ML", control=list(opt="optim"))
```

**cave** some models may run endless

```
slope3      <- lme(measure ~ timepoint, data=data, random= ~ timepoint|subject/event, 
                   na.action=na.exclude, method="ML", control = list(opt="optim"))
covariance  <- lme(measure ~ timepoint, data=data, random= ~ timepoint|subject, 
                   correlation=corAR1(),na.action = na.exclude, method="ML")
covariance2 <- lme(measure ~ timepoint, data=data, random= ~ timepoint|subject, 
                   correlation=corAR1(0), na.action=na.exclude, method="ML", 
                   control=list(opt="optim"))
covariance3 <- lme(measure ~ timepoint, data=data, random= ~ timepoint|subject, 
                   correlation=corAR1(0), na.action=na.exclude, method="ML", 
                   control=list(maxlter=1000))
```

Comment: What are the "cave" bits for?

Comment: Thank you for the remark Glen_b, it is a warning, because at least on my computer some models run endless and can crash R. I have added a comment to make that clearer.

Comment: The main issue here is treating `timepoint` as categorical.  That means that fitting a term like `timepoint|subject` will require fitting a full 10x10 variance-covariance matrix (55 distinct parameters) across 13 subjects.  It would be much more practical to fit `timepoint` as a continuous covariate ...

Comment: Ah, with the edit and the explanation, it makes more sense. I couldn't see what underground hollows had to do with it.

Comment: Dear Ben Bolker, Dear @AdamO,  Thank your for the very helpful comments and explanations. I see your points and from the simulated data it was not clear, why timepoint is a categorical variable, but in fact the measurements were taken at different time points for example at the beginning of the recording, 2 minutes before the event, during the event, 1 minute, 2 minutes, 3 minutes, 5 minutes, 10 minutes after the event and at the end of the recording. That's why I treated it like a categorical and not like a continuous variable.

Answer (score 7):

@AdamO has done a good job identifying the specific error in your code.  Let me address the question more generally.  Here is how I simulate a linear mixed effects model:

Mixed effects models assume each unit has random effects drawn from a multivariate normal distribution.  (When a model is estimated, it is the variances and covariances of that multivariate normal that are being estimated for the random effects.)  I start by specifying this distribution and generating (pseudo-)random values to serve as the random effects.  It is often convenient to specify the variances as $1$, so that the covariance is the correlation between slopes and intercepts (which is easier for me to conceptualize).

```
library(MASS)
ni = 13                                                 # number of subjects
RE = mvrnorm(ni, mu=c(0,0), Sigma=rbind(c(1.0, 0.3),
                                        c(0.3, 1.0) ))
colnames(RE) = c("ints","slopes");  t(round(RE,2))
#         [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]  [,5]  [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
# ints    0.81 -0.52 -0.65 1.30 -0.29 -1.15 0.04 0.05 0.00 -0.29  2.40 -0.05 -0.47
# slopes -1.82  0.81 -0.70 1.28  0.82 -0.18 0.74 1.14 0.93 -0.20  0.04  0.68 -0.53
```

Next, I would generate my $X$ variables.  I can't really follow the logic of your example, so I will use `time` as my only regressor.

```
nj   = 10                              # number of timepoints
data = data.frame(ID   = rep(1:ni,   each=nj), 
                  time = rep(1:nj,   times=ni),
                  RE.i = rep(RE[,1], each=nj),
                  RE.s = rep(RE[,2], each=nj),
                  y    = NA                    )
head(data, 14)
#    ID time       RE.i       RE.s  y
# 1   1    1  0.8051709 -1.8152973 NA
# 2   1    2  0.8051709 -1.8152973 NA
# 3   1    3  0.8051709 -1.8152973 NA
# 4   1    4  0.8051709 -1.8152973 NA
# 5   1    5  0.8051709 -1.8152973 NA
# 6   1    6  0.8051709 -1.8152973 NA
# 7   1    7  0.8051709 -1.8152973 NA
# 8   1    8  0.8051709 -1.8152973 NA
# 9   1    9  0.8051709 -1.8152973 NA
# 10  1   10  0.8051709 -1.8152973 NA
# 11  2    1 -0.5174601  0.8135761 NA
# 12  2    2 -0.5174601  0.8135761 NA
# 13  2    3 -0.5174601  0.8135761 NA
# 14  2    4 -0.5174601  0.8135761 NA
```

Having generated your random effects and your regressors, you can specify the data generating process.  Since you want some randomly missed timepoints, there is a level of additional complexity here.  (Note that these data are missing completely at random; for more on simulating missing data, see: [How to simulate the different types of missing data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/184747/7290).)

```
y       = with(data, (0 + RE.i) + (.3 + RE.s)*time + rnorm(n=ni*nj, mean=0, sd=1))
m       = rbinom(n=ni*nj, size=1, prob=.1)  
y[m==1] = NA
data$y  = y
head(data, 14)
#    ID time       RE.i       RE.s           y
# 1   1    1  0.8051709 -1.8152973  -0.8659219
# 2   1    2  0.8051709 -1.8152973  -3.6961761
# 3   1    3  0.8051709 -1.8152973  -4.2188711
# 4   1    4  0.8051709 -1.8152973  -4.8380769
# 5   1    5  0.8051709 -1.8152973  -5.4126362
# 6   1    6  0.8051709 -1.8152973  -8.3894008
# 7   1    7  0.8051709 -1.8152973          NA
# 8   1    8  0.8051709 -1.8152973 -11.3710128
# 9   1    9  0.8051709 -1.8152973 -14.2095646
# 10  1   10  0.8051709 -1.8152973 -14.7627970
# 11  2    1 -0.5174601  0.8135761   0.2018260
# 12  2    2 -0.5174601  0.8135761          NA
# 13  2    3 -0.5174601  0.8135761   3.9232935
# 14  2    4 -0.5174601  0.8135761          NA
```

At this point, you can fit your model.  I typically use the `lme4` package.

```
library(lme4)
summary(lmer(y~time+(time|ID), data))
# Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
# Formula: y ~ time + (time | ID)
#    Data: data
# 
# REML criterion at convergence: 378.3
# 
# Scaled residuals: 
#      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -2.48530 -0.61824 -0.08551  0.59285  2.70687 
# 
# Random effects:
#   Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
#   ID       (Intercept) 0.9970   0.9985        
#            time        0.8300   0.9110   -0.05
#   Residual             0.7594   0.8715        
# Number of obs: 112, groups:  ID, 13
# 
# Fixed effects:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value
# (Intercept)  0.03499    0.33247   0.105
# time         0.53454    0.25442   2.101
# 
# Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#      (Intr)
# time -0.100
```

Comment: Dear Ben Bolker, Dear AdamO, Dear gung, 

Thank your for the very helpful comments and explanations. I see your points and from the simulated data it was not clear, why timepoint is a categorical variable, but in fact the measurements were taken at different time points for example at the beginning of the recording, 2 minutes before the event, during the event, 1 minute, 2 minutes, 3 minutes, 5 minutes, 10 minutes after the event and at the end of the recording. That's why I treated it like a categorical and not like a continuous variable.

Comment: @Kev, I am the only person who is notified of your comment. If you want others to be notified, you need to comment after AdamO's answer, or in the comments under the Q w/ the "@" symbol before BenBolker's user name (as I have done for you here). That said, your comment doesn't make much sense, but you should be able to adapt the code I provide here. If you are focused on some event, you can use `-2, 0, 1, ...` for the `time` variable & even add a linear spline term w/ a knot at the event, if that's what you're after.

Comment: @gung If I interpret your set-up correctly, all random effects would have intercepts and slopes drawn from the same bivariate normal distribution, such that the intercept and slope for any given RE would be correlated. So, here is my follow-up question re: recreating model [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/79360/67822): if for instance a RE is the different trees in the sample, there wouldn't be slope - only intercept. So, in that case, would I draw the intercepts from a simple `rnorm`. And if so, where would there be any correlation?

Comment: [This is where I am](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/trees%20mixed%20random%20effects).

Comment: @AntoniParellada, by default mixed effects models assume the random effects are normally distributed (ie multivariate normal), although it is possible to deal with other distributions. You can have a set of independent random effects; that would amount to setting the off diagonal elements of the covariance matrix to 0 or using multiple `rnorm()` calls. If you only have a random intercept, none of that applies & you can just use `rnorm()`. I don't have time to try to work through your larger situation right now; I'll try to get to it when I can.

Comment: @gung No problem. I will ask formally on the site. Just if you don't mind it,  a quick question, Is the covariance between Intercept and Slope for every random effect? Or  between intercepts (and slopes) across different variables?

Comment: @AntoniParellada, I don't understand your question. You can have a covariance or not between any random effects, just as any or your covariates could be correlated.

Answer (score 5):

There is an obvious mistake in your simulation. However, in general, it's impossible to generate data so that a random slopes model is *guaranteed* to converge.

The fix you need to apply is to timepoint. Timepoint is a factor. You should not be using a factor level variable in a random slopes model, it is completely aliased with random intercept.

Try

```
data$timepoint <- as.numeric(data$timepoint)
```

and

```
slope <- lme(measure ~ factor(timepoint), data=data, 
  random=~timepoint|subject, na.action=na.exclude, method="ML")
```

This converges instantly. It's also appropriately nested within other models.

Make good use of the `try()` command to "capture" simulation output with converge-fails. You can explore interesting behavior with numerical solvers that are "at the boundary" of their capabilities.