# How to simulate data to demonstrate mixed effects with R (lme4)?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

As a counterpart to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/187978/67822), I worked on simulating data with continuous variables, lending themselves to correlated intercepts and slopes.

Although there are great posts on this topic [on the site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/162735/67822), and [outside the site](http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.in/2012/10/hierarchical-linear-models-and-lmer.html), I had difficulties in coming across a beginning-to-end example with simulated data that paralleled a simple, real-life scenario.

So the question is how to simulate these data, and "test" it with `lmer`. Nothing new to many, but possibly useful to many others searching to understand mixed models.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you prefer a blog article format, [Hierarchical linear models and lmer](http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.com/2012/10/hierarchical-linear-models-and-lmer.html) is an article I wrote that features a simulation with random slopes and intercepts. Here's the simulation code I used:

```
rm(list = ls())
set.seed(2345)

N <- 30
unit.df <- data.frame(unit = c(1:N), a = rnorm(N))

head(unit.df, 3)
unit.df <-  within(unit.df, {
  E.alpha.given.a <-  1 - 0.15 * a
  E.beta.given.a <-  3 + 0.3 * a
})
head(unit.df, 3)

library(mvtnorm)
q = 0.2
r = 0.9
s = 0.5
cov.matrix <- matrix(c(q^2, r * q * s, r * q * s, s^2), nrow = 2,
                     byrow = TRUE)
random.effects <- rmvnorm(N, mean = c(0, 0), sigma = cov.matrix)
unit.df$alpha <- unit.df$E.alpha.given.a + random.effects[, 1]
unit.df$beta <- unit.df$E.beta.given.a + random.effects[, 2]
head(unit.df, 3)

J <- 30
M = J * N  #Total number of observations
x.grid = seq(-4, 4, by = 8/J)[0:30]

within.unit.df <-  data.frame(unit = sort(rep(c(1:N), J)), j = rep(c(1:J),
                              N), x =rep(x.grid, N))
flat.df = merge(unit.df, within.unit.df)

flat.df <-  within(flat.df, y <-  alpha + x * beta + 0.75 * rnorm(n = M))
simple.df <-  flat.df[, c("unit", "a", "x", "y")]
head(simple.df, 3)

library(lme4)
my.lmer <-  lmer(y ~ x + (1 + x | unit), data = simple.df)
cat("AIC =", AIC(my.lmer))
my.lmer <-  lmer(y ~ x + a + x * a + (1 + x | unit), data = simple.df)
summary(my.lmer)
```

Comment: Ben, Thank you for your answer! I'm really busy right now, but I'll look into it carefully as soon as I get a chance. + on credit :-)

Answer (score 1):

The data is completely fictional and the code that I used to generate it can be found [here](https://github.com/RInterested/SIMULATIONS_and_PROOFS/blob/master/Athletes%20mixed%20effects).

The idea is that we would take measurements on `glucose concentrations` on a group of `30` `athletes` at the completion of `15` `races` in relation to the concentration of the made-up `amino acid A` (`AAA`) in these athletes blood.

The model is: `lmer(glucose ~ AAA + (1 + AAA | athletes)`

There is a fixed effect slope (glucose ~ amino acid A concentration); however, the slopes also vary between different athletes with a `mean = 0` and `sd = 0.5`, while the intercepts for the different athletes are spread a random effects around `0` with `sd = 0.2`. Further there is a correlation between intercepts and slopes of 0.8 within the same athlete.

These random effects are added to a chosen `intercept = 1` for fixed effects, and `slope = 2`.

The values of the concentration of glucose were calculated as `alpha + AAA * beta + 0.75 * rnorm(observations)`, meaning the intercept for every athlete (i.e. `1 + random effects changes in the intercept`) $+$ the concentration of amino acid, `AAA` $*$ the slope for every athlete (i.e. `2 + random effect changes in slopes for each athlete`) $+$ `noise` ($\epsilon$), which we set up to have a `sd = 0.75`.

So the data look like:

```
      athletes races      AAA   glucose
    1        1     1  51.79364 104.26708
    2        1     2  49.94477 101.72392
    3        1     3  45.29675  92.49860
    4        1     4  49.42087 100.53029
    5        1     5  45.92516  92.54637
    6        1     6  51.21132 103.97573
    ...
```

Unrealistic levels of glucose, but still...

The summary returns:

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 athletes (Intercept) 0.006045 0.07775      
          AAA         0.204471 0.45218  1.00
 Residual             0.545651 0.73868      
Number of obs: 450, groups:  athletes, 30

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.31146    0.35845 401.90000   3.659 0.000287 ***
AAA           1.93785    0.08286  29.00000  23.386  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The random effects correlation is `1` instead of `0.8`. The `sd = 2` for the random variation in intercepts is interpreted as `0.07775`. The standard deviation of `0.5` for random changes in slopes among athletes is calculated as `0.45218`. The noise set up with a standard deviation `0.75` was returned as `0.73868`.

The intercept of fixed effects was supposed to be `1`, and we got `1.31146`. For the slope it was supposed to be `2`, and the estimate was `1.93785`.

Fairly close!

Comment: The simulated model is parallel to the example [here](http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.in/2012/10/hierarchical-linear-models-and-lmer.html) giving it a concrete, real-life scenario *and* eliminating the $a$ variable (which in the case I simulate would simply be a single, random $N(0,1)$ observation for each athlete) that was used both as a regressor in its own right, as well as to generate random intercepts and slopes, as an intermediate step.