# Extracting random effects from glmer()

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, random-effects-model

I currently am fitting a mixed model on a data set of n=20,000 and my model takes the following form

`mask_model=glmer(y~x_1+x_2+(1+x_3||x_4)+(1|x_5),data=fake_data,family="binomial)`

So we have a random intercept and slope for each `x_4` group, and a random intercept for each `x_5` group.

`x_3` takes one of 18 values, `x_4` takes one of three values, and `x_5` takes one of 20,000 values.

I am able to fit `mask_model` in a few minutes. However when I attempt to extract the random effects from this model via `ranef(mask_model)` my computer just hangs. This strikes me as strange as I would think when I make the original `glmer()` it would calculate these random effects. If I exclude the random intercept involving `x_5`, or if I make `x_5` only take one of 5000 values then `ranef()` seems to work.

Would greatly appreciate any insight into why this might be happening and  a potential workaround.

---

I receive the following output from summary(mask_model)

[image: testmodel]

When I run getME(mask_model, "b") I get a 8625x1 vector, (I have 8619 id's and 3 provinces). It appears to be that this is the conditional mode of the random effects, but ideally I could somehow extract what the id random effect is for each participant, and the random slope/intercept for each province (if that is possible; unfortunately ranef(mask_model) just hangs in R).

Comment: Please include the output from `summary(test_model)` ? Also what happens if you use `getME(test_model, "b")` ?

Comment: Have added this in a comment above. I have described what `getME()` returns above; is the correct way to interpret this vector by `using getME(mask_model,'Zt')` to find out which entry of the large vector corresponds to which random effect?

Comment: The output doesn't correspond to the model.  Anyway `Zt` is the transpose of the model matrix for the random effects so `Z` determines how the random effects are mapped to the response. But the question in the OP was how to extract the (conditional modes of the) random effects themselves and that's what `getME(test_model, "b")` should do.

Comment: OK I understand now, I see that `"b"` gives the conditional modes and then `rownames(Z_t)` give which conditional mode corresponds to which grouping (arranged id first, province slope second, province intercept third). Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the conditional modes of the random effects using

```
getME(test_model, "b")
```

You can extract the model matrix $Z$ for the random effects using

```
getME(mask_model,'Zt')
```

and transpose it.  This matrix determines how the random effects are "mapped" to the response in the mixed model equation:

$$ Y = X\beta + Zb + \epsilon$$

You may find this answer to be helpful in understanding how the $Z$ model matrix works:
[What are the steps to simulate data for a linear model with random slopes and random intercepts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/488188/what-are-the-steps-to-simulate-data-for-a-linear-model-with-random-slopes-and-ra/488346#488346)

Comment: Great answer and very clear, thank you very much for the help.