# Random effect with compound symmetric covariance structure in glmmTMB

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, glmm, glmmtmb

I have a dataset of abundance of a kind of rodents(AA) in 63 sites, and want to know which environmental factors can explain the rodent abundance, and because the sampling sites are basically locate in two parts of my research area (northern part and southern part, `NS`), I used `glmmTMB` function to build a negative-binomial mixed model with `NS` as
the random effect.

Random effect are fitted with `compound symmetric` variance-covariance structure, here is the code:

```
glmmTMB(AA~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + cs(1|sites/NS),  
                         family="nbinom2"(link = "log"), data=Rglmm2)
```

And the error returns

> Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See
> vignette('troubleshooting')

According to the information in `vignette('troubleshooting')`, it looks like the setting of my random effect and the variance-covariance structure part (`cs(1|sites/NS)`) went wrong, since `sites` are nested in the `NS`, how should I set it up right?

Thanks!

Comment: If sites are nested with geographic region, then you want to specify the nesting as *NS/sites*. See [Mixed Effects Model with Nesting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79360/mixed-effects-model-with-nesting) and also this [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification).

Comment: @dipetkov Thanks for your information! I'll try using these formula